# Bash - remove dashes and new-lines before replacing new-lines with spaces

Tags: bash, awk, sed, command-line, tr

I have a bunch of text files in the following format:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consetetur sadipscing elitr,
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
invidunt ut labore et dolore
magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
voluptua. - At vero eos et accu-
sam et justo duo dolores et ea
rebum. - Stet clita kasd guber-
gren, no sea takimata sanctus
est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

How can I print this as continuous text on the command line, but with removing the syllable division on the line ends:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. - At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. - Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

I could use `tr '\n' ' '` to convert the new-lines into spaces

The problem is `tr` can only replace one character and I would need some command to remove the `-\n` in advance. **How can I achieve this on the bash comman-line?**

Comment: Note that there may be cases where you want to _keep_ the hyphens (e.g. in “a back-of-`\n`the-envelope calculation”).  There may be no practical way to programmatically distinguish those cases from the others.

Comment: @gidds you are 100% right. There is also situations where you want to keep the paragraph. Though the answers to my question did help me a lot to make life easier ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Using `awk`:**

```
awk -F'-$' '{ printf "%s", sep $1; sep=/-$/?"":OFS } END{ print "" }' infile
```

with the `-F'-$'`, we defined the [**F**ield **S**eparator](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Field-Separators) to single hyphen at the end of line, so with this and by taking the first field `$1`, we will always have the line without that hyphen for those line having this hyphen or still entire line for those not having that hyphen.

then we do simply printing it with a *`sep`* in between but that changes when reading the next line to empty-string if current line was ending with a hyphen otherwise to OFS ([**O**utput **F**ield **S**eparator](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Output-Separators), default is Space character).

at the [*`END{...}`* block](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#BEGIN_002fEND) we are adding a final newline character to make it [a POSIX text file](/q/446237/72456), if you don't want that to be added, just remove that part.

---

**Using `sed`, alternatively:**

```
sed ':loop /-$/N;s/-\n//;t loop; N;s/\n/ /;t loop' infile
```

- **:loop**

  - if a line ended with a hyphen (testing with `/-$/`), do read the **N**ext line and replace the "hyphen+`\n`ewline" with an empty string.
    if substitution was successful (testing with `t`), then jump to the label *loop* and process the next line and skip executing rest of the code.
  - else, read the **N**ext line and replace the embedded `\n`ewline in between those two lines with a space character.
    if substitution here was also successful, then jump to the label *loop* and process the next line.

Answer (score 4):

Another `perl` solution (assuming the last line doesn't end with `-` character):

```bsh
perl -pe 's/-\n//; s/\n/ / if !eof'
```

Unlike `sed` or `awk`, the record separator can be directly manipulated using `perl`. So, it is easy to delete if `-\n` is matched. `s/\n/ / if !eof` will then replace remaining newlines with space, except for the last line.

If you don't care about an extra space at the end, you can remove the `if !eof` part.

Comment: Could also use `perl -0777 -pe 's/-\n//g; s/\n/ /g; s/ $/\n/'` without worrying about the last line.

Comment: `perl -0777 -wpl -e 's/(\w)-\n(\w)/$1$2/g; s/\n/ /g; s/ $/\n/;' lorem.txt` in case a dash character appears at the end of a line, without actually hyphenating a word

Answer (score 3):

1. Remove dashes used for hyphenation at the end of lines (joining hyphenated lines with the next line in the process).
2. Replace newlines with spaces.

```bsh
sed -e ':again' -e '/[[:alpha:]]-$/ { N; s/-\n//; b again; }' file |
paste -s -d ' ' -
```

This uses `sed` join hyphenated lines.  It does this by detecting lines that have dashes that are immediately preceded by a letter at the end of lines. By matching `[[:alpha:]]` in front of the dash, I'm more certain that I'm only removing dashes used for hyphenation. The hyphenated lines are then joined with the next line by reading in the next line with `N` (which inserts a literal newline character) and deleting the `-\n`.  The joined line is then re-checked for further hyphenation (this is what the `b again` branch to the `again` label does).

The `paste` utility is then used to paste all lines into one continuous line. The `-s` option is used to concatenate all lines into a single line, and `-d ' '` is used to specify the delimiter character used in the concatenation of the lines.

I could have used `tr '\n' ' '` in place of the `paste` command that I ended up with, but that would have given me an unterminated line (no newline character at the end).

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how you'd want blank lines handled this:

```
$ awk -v RS= '{gsub(/-\n/,""); $1=$1} 1' file
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. - At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. - Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

or this (if your awk supports multi-char RS, e.g. GNU awk):

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' '{gsub(/-\n/,""); $1=$1} 1' file
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. - At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. - Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

may be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Using the **POSIX sed** stream editor utility.

```
sed -e ':a
  $!N
  s/-\n//;ta
  s/\n/ /;ta
' file
```

---

With **awk** utility, we setup a loop to read the next line and manipulate the ORS for printing the previous line.

```
awk '
{
  while (getline t > 0) {
    ORS = sub(/-$/, "") ? "" : OFS
    print
    $0 = t
  }
  ORS = RS
}
1' file
```

---

We can rearrange the output record separator `$\`  based on the condition of the current record.

```
perl -lpe '
  $\ =   eof  ? $/
     : s/-$// ? $,
     :          $"
     ;
' file
```

- `$/` is the input record separator and defaults to a newline.
- `$"` is the array element separator under quotes and defaults to a space.
- `$,` is the output field separator and defaults to an empty string.